# How to plot lines between multiple x,y points in matplotlib/basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, mapping, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot a number of lines between 2 different X and Y points in matplotlib using basemap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Map=pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx')

lat=Map['Start Latitude'] 
long=Map['Start Longitude'] 
lat1=Map['Fin Latitude'] 
long2=Map['Fin Longitude']

x,y=m(lon.values,lat.values)
plt=m.scatter(x,y, marker="o", latlon=False)
```

For example:

```
Line1 would be between 1x,1y and 1x1,1y1
Line3 would be between 2x,2y and 2x1,2y1
Line3 would be between 3x,3y and 3x1,3y1
etc
```

where "x", "y", "x1" and "y1" are in separate columns ("start latitude", "start longitude", "fin latitude" "fin longitude").

There would be 100+ different lines

I can plot the "start latitude" and "start longitude" in the above (using `x,y=m(lon.values,lat.values)` and `plt=m.scatter(x,y, marker="o", latlon=False)`, but can't plot the second point and connect a line to it.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Currently your question is too broad. You didn't provide any data and so people will have to first create a sample data set and then write a code from scratch for you. Perhaps, since you are  a new contributor, I would suggest to please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, there are some undefined things in your question.

Comment: What is `m`? Are you using `basemap`? That's quite distinct from regular `matplotlib` in my experience and would deserve the tag.

Comment: In general, you use `plt.plot([x1,x2], [y1,y2])` to plot a line connecting the points. You can put this in a for loop as the simplest case where the loop will run over your x,y values which can be read using `np.loadtxt` for example from the file having the data.

Comment: @Bazingaa basemap is a whole other kettle of fish :)

Comment: You've clarified it's basemap but you still need to provide the [mcve] suggested originally. I've added the tag for you.

Comment: @roganjosh: Unfortunately, I am still vegetarian ;)

Comment: As you can see, that's illegible in a comment. You can [edit] your question to include the relevant info.

Comment: I've tried to edit the comment Roganjosh. Hope it is a little clearer. Appreciate the help and pointers. Hopefully next time I ask a question it will be a little smoother!

Comment: You may look into the answer I just provided to find out what is meant by a [mcve]. I.e. an example that is runnable by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `LineCollection` here due to the "100+" lines. Of course you first need to project the coordinates in the basemap system. Then you can stack them again into a numpy array and create the segment array for the `LineCollection`.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


df = pd.DataFrame({"lon1" : np.random.randint(-15,30,10),
                   "lat1" : np.random.randint(33,66,10),
                   "lon2" : np.random.randint(-15,30,10),
                   "lat2" : np.random.randint(33,66,10)})

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-12,llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlon=50,urcrnrlat=69.,
             resolution='i', projection='tmerc', lat_0 = 48.9, lon_0 = 15.3)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.72, color='gray')
m.drawcountries(zorder=0, color='gray')


lon1, lat1 = m(df.lon1.values, df.lat1.values)
lon2, lat2 = m(df.lon2.values, df.lat2.values)

pts = np.c_[lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2].reshape(len(lon1), 2, 2)
plt.gca().add_collection(LineCollection(pts, color="crimson", label="Lines"))

m.plot(lon1, lat1, marker="o", ls="", label="Start")
m.plot(lon2, lat2, marker="o", ls="", label="Fin")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]